# csv file reading issue ,contain ' # ' in value

Tags: python-3.7

my data file contain on 26 row value  1 column value are " sample # ",when I try to read i get error,Please help

I hade tried in three ways,

1) `pd.read_csv('/home/ami/test/st/st_04042018A.txt', delimiter=",") # getting error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 13: invalid start byte` ------ error

2) `csv = np.genfromtxt('/home/ami/test/st/st_04042018A.txt', delimiter=",")` ------ same error

3)

```
c=open(r'/home/ami/test/st/st_04042018A.txt')
c=c.read()
```

----same error

please help to read the file.

Comment: Could you share the error?

Comment: `utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 13: invalid start byte`. It's written after the first example.